# Missing turtle_tf_message_filter on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was working through the [tf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials), and in [the part about message filters](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter), I had an error when I launched the `turtle_tf_sensor.lauch`.

```
roslaunch turtle_tf turtle_tf_sensor.launch
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [turtle_tf/turtle_tf_message_filter]: can't locate node [turtle_tf_message_filter] in package [turtle_tf]
```

Indeed, there is no `turtle_tf_message_filter` file in `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/turtle_tf` on my Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit PC. The package was install via the apt `ros-hydro-turtle-tf` package.

But the file is in the [Github repo](https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/tree/hydro-devel/turtle_tf/src) on the hydro-devel branch so I think there is an issue with the packaging for Ubuntu 12.04 but I do not know where to report that issue.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205953/missing-turtle_tf_message_filter-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the `CMakeLists.txt` of `turtle_tf` ([here](https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/blob/4d19e966536e992633de2a3ef1de00e281cc0083/turtle_tf/CMakeLists.txt#L26-L30)), it would indeed seem to be the case that the `turtle_tf_message_filter` node is not installed ( the other C++ nodes are installed on [these lines](https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/blob/4d19e966536e992633de2a3ef1de00e281cc0083/turtle_tf/CMakeLists.txt#L47-L52)).

As for reporting this: I'd just post an issue on the [geometry_tutorials/issues](https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/issues) tracker.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) on 2015-03-26**:
Thank you gvdhoorn.

Issue posted [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry_tutorials/issues/18). I hope it is clear.